# Many to many update in MongoDB without transactions

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections with a many-to-many relationship. I want to store an array of linked ObjectIds in both documents so that I can take Document A and retrieve all linked Document B's quickly, and vice versa.

Creating this link is a two step process

1. Add Document A's ObjectId to Document B
2. Add Document B's ObjectId to Document A

After watching a MongoDB video I found this to be the recommended way of storing a many-to-many relationship between two collections

I need to be sure that both updates are made. What is the recommended way of robustly dealing with this crucial two step process without a transaction?

I could condense this relationship into a single link collection, the advantage being a single update with no chance of Document B missing the link to Document A. The disadvantage being that I'm not really using MongoDB as intended. But, because there is only a single update, it seems more robust to have a link collection that defines the many-to-many relationship.

Should I use safe mode and manually check the data went in afterwards and try again on failure? Or should I represent the many-to-many relationship in just one of the collections and rely on an index to make sure I can still quickly get the linked documents?

Any recommendations? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**@Gareth**, you have multiple legitimate ways to do this. So they key concern is how you plan to query for the data, (i.e.: *what queries need to be fast*)

Here are a couple of methods.

**Method #1: the "links" collection**

You could build a collection that simply contains mappings between the collections.

*Pros:*

- Supports atomic updates so that data is not lost

*Cons:*

- Extra query when trying to move between collections

**Method #2: store copies of smaller mappings in larger collection**

For example: you have millions of `Products`, but only a hundred `Categories`. Then you would store the `Categories` as an array inside each `Product`.

*Pros:*

- Smallest footprint
- Only need one update

*Cons:*

- Extra query if you go the "wrong way"

**Method #3: store copies of all mappings in both collections**

(what you're suggesting)

*Pros:*

- Single query access to move between either collection

*Cons:*

- Potentially large indexes
- Needs transactions (?)

Let's talk about "needs transactions". There are several ways to do transactions and it really depends on what type of safety you require.

> Should I use safe mode and manually check the data went in afterwards and try again on failure?

You can definitely do this. You'll have to ask yourself, what's the worst that happens if only one of the saves fails?

**Method #4: queue the change**

I don't know if you've ever worked with queues, but if you have some leeway you can build a simple queue and have different jobs that update their respective collections.

This is a much more advanced solution. I would tend to go with #2 or #3.

Comment: Great answer thank you. #2 looks the best option. The relationship is one sided by a factor of roughly 10, so there's my answer right there! I would rather lose a small amount of performance than face possible data issues. MongoDB is so fast anyway it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a dedicated collection holding the relations between A and B as dedicated rows/documents as one would do it in a RDBMS. You can modify the relation table with one operation which is of course atomic.

Comment: Thanks, I do consider this approach in my question, but in a video I watched this was not recommended as the MongoDB way

Comment: Are videos an authorative source of information? MongoDB only provides atomicity for single operation. If transactional support is important: either don't use MongoDB or use MongoDB as described. You can't have everything.

Comment: It was a video of a presentation given by a member of the MongoDB core team. I'm trying to make the "should I use MongdoDB" call at the moment

Comment: The video was Schema Design with MongoDB by Kyle Banker : http://mongodb.blip.tv/file/3704083/

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use safe mode and manually check the data went in afterwards and try again on failure?

Yes this an approach, but there is an another - you can implement an optimistic transaction. It has some overhead and limitations but it guarantees data consistency. I wrote an example and some explanation on a [GitHub](https://github.com/rystsov/mongodb-transaction-example) page.